# Facebook Graph java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made an app that gets some Facebook post through Facebook Graph. Everything works great on my phones(Cubot Note S && UMI Diamond), but when I try to open the app on other phone in my case LG K10(2017). I get the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException:` and I don't know why, Because on the first phones this app worked very well.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.util.List com.gireada.***.Posts2.getData()' on a null object reference
at com.gireada.***.MainActivity$3$1.onCompleted(MainActivity.java:153)
```

Here is the line

```
for (int i = 0; i < (variabila2.getPosts().getData().size()) - 1; i++)
```

Every time when I try to access `variabila2.getPosts()....` it gives me this error:

**First two phone have 6.0 android and LG have 7.0, could be this be a problem?**

I made `GraphCall` with this method:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                accessToken,
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                    System.out.println(object);
                                    Log.d("Profil ", object.toString());


globalObject.setCurentToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
                                    String nome;
                                        /*if (jObjResponse.has("name")) {
                                            nome = 

jObjResponse.getString("name");
                                                globalObject.setNume(nome);
                                            }
                                            if (jObjResponse.has("id")) {
                                                nome = jObjResponse.getString("id");
                                                globalObject.setID_User(nome);
                                            }*/
                                            variabila2 = new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(), Variable2.class);
    //                                            System.out.println(variabila2.getPosts().toString());
    //                                            Log.d("Link ", variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(0).getLink());
                                            for (int i = 0; i < (variabila2.getPosts().getData().size()) - 1; i++)
                                            {
                                                Log.d("Link ", variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getLink());
                                                if (variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getCreated_time() != null)
                                                    globalObject.setCreated_global(variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getCreated_time(), i);
                                                else
                                                    globalObject.setCreated_global(null, i);

                                                globalObject.setLink_global(variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getLink(), i);
                                                Log.d("Link Personal", variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getLink());
                                                if (variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getFull_picture() != null)
                                                    globalObject.setLink_pictures(variabila2.getPosts().getData().get(i).getFull_picture(), i);
                                                else
                                                    globalObject.setLink_pictures(null, i);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,posts.limit(100){link,created_time,description,full_picture}");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();

**Variable2 class**

    public class Variable2
    {
        public String status;
        public Feed feed;
        Posts2 posts;
        Picture picture;
        public Variable2(Posts2 posts2) {
            this.posts = posts2;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        public Feed getFeed() {
            return feed;
        }
        public void setFeed(Feed feed) {
            this.feed = feed;
        }
        public Posts2 getPosts() {
            return posts;
        }
        public void setPosts(Posts2 posts) {
            this.posts = posts;
        }
        public Picture getPicture() {
            return picture;
        }
        public void setPicture(Picture picture) {
            this.picture = picture;
        }
    }

**Post2 class**


    public class Posts2 {
        public List<Item2> data;

        public Posts2(List<Item2> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public List<Item2> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(List<Item2> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

**Item2 class**

    public class Item2 {
        public String link;
        public String created_time;
        public String full_picture;
        public String description;
        public String id;
        public Item2(String link, String created_time, String description, String full_picture, String id) {
            this.link = link;
            this.created_time = created_time;
            this.description = description;
            this.full_picture = full_picture;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getLink() {
            return link;
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }

        public String getCreated_time() {
            return created_time;
        }

        public void setCreated_time(String created_time) {
            this.created_time = created_time;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getFull_picture() {
            return full_picture;
        }

        public void setFull_picture(String full_picture) {
            this.full_picture = full_picture;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
```

This works on my first phones, but on this phone (maybe on other phones to) it doesn't work.

Please help me if you have an idea as to this problem.

Comment: add your json response here.

Comment: {"id":"2016399981939546","name":"Grigore Saveluc Rodica"}. Now i see why is give me NullPoint. But why does't give me post on this phone.                                   On Cubot: {"id":"1813718138656862","name":"Iulian Grigore","posts":{"data":[{"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/BananaGiveaway\/phot......

Comment: your response **variabila2** is not jsonarray. this is a JSONObject.

Comment: you add your full json response add with your question then get proper idea where you are stuck.

Comment: Variable2 variabila2; this is how i define **variabila2**   i convert json to gson and stoc all data to on variable2 variabiable.    **new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(), Variable2.class);**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I don't put all permision on login button.

```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("user_posts", "public_profile", "email"));
```

Thanks all for your help. That's why i get only few data.

```
  {"id":"2016399981939546","name":"Grigore Saveluc Rodica"}
```